# iPhone URL encoding Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Have a slight problem.  Trying to post XML to a server.  To do this, I have to encode the XML string in URL format.

```
NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xmlValue=%@",[post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

That's what I have and it works for all the characters EXCEPT the '='.  This does not get converted to %3D.  Has anyone else ever had this problem before? Am I specifying the wrong encoding type?  I have tried "NSUTF8StringEncoding" as well.

This is a little piece of the XML string:

```
@"<xml-service application=\"broadcast\" type=\"REQUEST\"><identity token=\"xxxxxxxx\".....
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: This question actually helped me, making me aware of the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`-funtion. Thanks! :D

Comment: No prob!  Still need to figure out why it's not converting the '=' though...

Comment: Yeah, I also just stumbled up to that just now..

Comment: One thing to be careful of is if you are sending xml in the url, the url is restricted to 2k characters so if your xml gets big it will be truncated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
  NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

*[Source](http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/)*

Comment: Ok I saw that, how do I convert that to data once I encode it?  The only thing I can find is:  NSData *postData = [encodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  Does that ruin the encoding when I go to post it?

Comment: It should work ok since the string is already encoded. I don't think you necessarily need the allowLossyConversion part though.

Comment: Ok it must be another problem then.  The server is claiming that I am sending invalid XML for some reason.

Comment: But I do suppose that was the solution for my initial problem :) The string was successfully encoded. Thanks!

Comment: It also solved cyrillic issue (total ignoring of cyrillic chars/text). Thanx!

Comment: You should avoid link-only answers, I've edited the answer for you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. I found this helpful.

```
NSString *sampleUrl = @"http://www.google.com/search.jsp?params=Java Developer";
NSString* encodedUrl = [sampleUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: can u plz suggest the reason for negative feedback?