# NSXMLParser Doesn't Parse when URL contains chars from different language

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsurl

hi there I am working on a program that sends requests via XML Webservice and parses the data using NSXML parser.

I've used that method for anything on my program and it works flawlessly until I had this:

NSXML Parser returns data and parses when the URL is like that:

```
http://someasp.netserver/xmlservices/service1.asmx/getSales?date1=01.03.2011%2000:00:00&date2=%2023.03.2011%2000:00:00%20&Name=JOHN
```

but when I change the URL to this:

```
http://someasp.netserver/xmlservices/service1.asmx/getSales?date1=01.03.2011%2000:00:00&date2=%2023.03.2011%2000:00:00%20&Name=JÜRGEN
```

it doesn't return anything.

I copy and paste those URL addresses into a web browser and I can see the XML results but on the iPhone NSXMLparser just ignores the parsing and returns nothing.

I have a list of 15 "Name" values in my program, and whenever the name contains characters like 'ö,ü,ş,İ,ç' it just returns zero, otherwise it's working normally.

Thanks for helping.

Also, here's my parsing code in the program :

```
NSURL *URL=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:testURL]; //test url is the request string
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL :URL];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

Comment: i tried both of ur url in my browser but it seems to me they are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform URL encoding, you can't just shove special characters into a URL as-is.

Please see this question:

[iPhone URL encoding Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924871/iphone-url-encoding-problem)

Or search for "iphone url encoding".

Comment: testURL = [testURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; solved my problem.