# Cyrillic NSString to Unicode in objective-c

Tags: c#, objective-c, unicode, encode

I want to send Cyrillic string as parameter over webservice from iPhone to .net framework server. How should I encode it correctly? I would like the result to be something like:

> "myParam=\U0438\U0422"

If it's doable, would it matter if it is Cyrillic or just Latin letters?

And how should I decode it on the server, where I am using C#?

Comment: Do everything in UTF-8. Then you don't have to encode anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the result to be something like "myParam=\U0438\U0422"

Really? That's not the standard for URL parameter encoding, which would be:

```
myParam=%d0%b8%d0%a2
```

assuming the UTF-8 encoding, which will be the default for an ASP.NET app. You don't need to manually decode anything then, the Request.QueryString/Form collections will give you native Unicode strings.

URL-encoding would normally be done using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, except that it's a bit broken. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3924871/18936) for background.

Answer (score -1):

The C# strings default encoding Unicode. So for you, it's enough to ensure that your string is encoded like unicode.

One time it's encoded like unicode, there is no any difference if you put there cyrilic, latin, arabic or whatever letters, should be enough to use correct Code Page.

**EDIT**

Was searching for.. good article here [Globalization Step by Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688114.aspx#ESC)

Correction by @chibacity note: even if default string encoding is Unicode in C#, Web Services in your case use UTF-8. (more flexible one)

Comment: The OP is describing a Web Service call. The encoding of the call is independent of the exact scheme used to encode strings in .Net. UTF-8 is the default for web services.

Comment: @chibacity: correct +1, just missed WebService part of the question. Corrected in edit...